# Large uploaded file won't display in Ubuntu One but is included in file usage

Tags: ubuntu-one

On Ubuntu 10.04, I uploaded a single 711 MB. My total file usage in Ubuntu One went up to 877MB, which is about right, but the file doesn't show in Ubuntu One so I can't download or delete it.

Either the file is there and I can't see it for some reason. Or the file is not there and the total file usage figure is wrong.

Does anyone know what has happened? I have a free account but am well below my 5GB limit.

Comment: Doesn't show on the web site you mean? Or doesn't show locally?

Comment: Hi there, it doesn't show on the website. I uploaded the file, it's not from a synced folder. I still have my local copy, I just want to free up storage space on Unbuntu One and delete the copy there - if it is there. I didn't delete it already - I just uploaded it, and the file size count increased, but the file never showed.

Comment: You uploaded it using the web site file upload UI? If so, it sounds like perhaps you navigated away while it was uploading or something similar. But you should probably file a support request at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact instead of asking here.

Comment: Yes, I uploaded via the web interface, not syncing. thanks dobey.

Comment: service is obsolete